# In iccube, How to link 2 many to many relations?

Tags: many-to-many, business-intelligence, iccube

Having **people stays** in an hospital, they can go thru different **Medical Units** and receive **Medical Acts**.

These Medical acts are related to a Medical Unit.

Using « single » many to many relationships, we are able to filter and break everything between :

- Medical Units & People Stays
- Medical Acts & People Stays

But, we are unable to filter and break correctly **to show the number of Acts done in 1 Medical Unit**

For example, Roger (Stay Nbr 2) is a Man, is 20 years old, stayed 1 day, for an amount of 10,
He went into 2 Medical Units (Radiologie, duration 1  & Orthopedie, Duration 0)
In Radiologie, he received the Act Examen, 10000 times

We understand that it certainly has to be a « cascading » Many to many relationship. **But, how to define it inside a cube ?**

Here is a set of data of the 3 source tables.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>People stays</th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>Stay Nbr</td><td>People Name</td><td>sex</td><td>Age</td><td>illness</td><td>Geo-Code</td><td>Stay Duration</td><td>Amount</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Robert</td><td>Homme</td><td>30</td><td>Rhume</td><td>55555</td><td>10</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Roger</td><td>Homme</td><td>20</td><td>Grippe</td><td>44444</td><td>1</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Marguerite</td><td>Femme</td><td>30</td><td>Rhume</td><td>55555</td><td>10</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Carole</td><td>Femme</td><td>20</td><td>Rougeole</td><td>44444</td><td>100</td><td>1000</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>Anne</td><td>Femme</td><td>50</td><td>Rougeole</td><td>99999</td><td>1000</td><td>100000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Medical Units</th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>Stay Nbr</td><td>ordered Mediacal Unit inside the Stay</td><td>Medical Unit</td><td>Medical Unit Duration</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Pneumologie</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Radiologie</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>Pneumologie</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>Orthopédie</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>5</td><td>Psychiatrie</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>Radiologie</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>Orthopédie</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>Orthopédie</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>Psychiatrie</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>Traumatologie</td><td>1000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Medical Acts</th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>Stay Nbr</td><td>ordered Mediacal Unit inside the Stay</td><td>Medical Unit</td><td>Act</td><td>nbr of acts</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>Pneumologie</td><td>Examen</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>Radiologie</td><td>Opération</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>Pneumologie</td><td>Examen</td><td>1000</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>Radiologie</td><td>Examen</td><td>10000</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>Orthopédie</td><td>Opération</td><td>100000</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>Orthopédie</td><td>Examen</td><td>100000</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>1</td><td>Psychiatrie</td><td>Examen</td><td>1000000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Edit - Added Additional information & Standalone cube and report to help understanding.**

I created a small standalone cube and iccube report to show and explain the issue, it can be downloaded there :

[Cube and Report showing the issue](https://mon-partage.fr/f/k4uLEvye/)

In the report, we can see that the system takes the Stays including « examen » acts, then, it merges these with all the stays including « Radiologie » Medical Unit, even though they are not linked…

[image]
Result expected for widget above is 1 instead of 11.

[image]
Results expected here are 11, 1, 10 instead of 11, 11, 10.